# Why did my bio get deleted?

Tags: support, profile-page

Why did my bio get deleted when I cleared my cache/cookies?

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about on SO or on Meta? Your [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411472/adam) appears fine; your Meta one is empty, but I suspect you just never filled it out. If you were using an unregistered account accidentally (i.e. you forgot to log in), it would've persisted until you deleted your cookies. If that's the case and you know the user ID of the other account, you can get a moderator to merge it into your registered account

Comment: no my SO one i added back- but it said something about being "a better non tech co-founder" maybe it was a different account but my photo and rating and history are all the same just my about was blank when i logged in again

Comment: @adam Hmm. I don't know then, I've never heard of that happening before